# Sliding ul list elements horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this function:

```
    function smoothAdd(id, text)
{
    var el = $('#' + id);

    var h = el.height();

    el.css({
        height:   h,
        overflow: 'hidden'
    });

    var ulPaddingTop    = parseInt(el.css('padding-top'));
    var ulPaddingBottom = parseInt(el.css('padding-bottom'));

    el.prepend('<li>' + text + '</li>');

    var first = $('li:first', el);
    var last  = $('li:last',  el);

    var foh = first.outerHeight();

    var heightDiff = foh - last.outerHeight();

    var oldMarginTop = first.css('margin-top');

    first.css({
        marginTop: 0 - foh,
        position:  'relative',
        top:       0 - ulPaddingTop
    });

    last.css('position', 'relative');

    el.animate({ height: h + heightDiff }, 1500)

    first.animate({ top: 0 }, 250, function() {
        first.animate({ marginTop: oldMarginTop }, 1000, function() {
            last.animate({ top: ulPaddingBottom }, 250, function() {
                last.remove();

                el.css({
                    height:   'auto',
                    overflow: 'visible'
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

That takes the id of the ul and the text i want to add, after adding the text it slides the new element from the top to bottom. it also removes the last element, every time that a new item is added. I want to make it to work horizontally, so instead of sliding from the top, sliding it from right to left, but don't know how to do that change.

Comment: Psst. Show the relevant HTML source for testing purposes.

Comment: Here is a fiddle example. I feel as though there are far easier ways to do this so will leave it up to others for solving - http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/ML7v5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `height` by `width`, `top` by `right` and `bottom` by `left`. After these replacements have been done, save the new function, and execute it.
**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uGkCq/**

```
function smoothAdd(id, text){
    var el = $('#' + id);
    var w = el.width();
    el.css({
        width:   w,
        overflow: 'hidden'
    });
    var ulPaddingLeft    = parseInt(el.css('padding-left'));
    var ulPaddingRight = parseInt(el.css('padding-right'));
    el.prepend('<li>' + text + '</li>');
    var first = $('li:first', el);
    var last  = $('li:last',  el);
    var fow = first.outerWidth();
    var widthDiff = fow - last.outerWidth();
    var oldMarginLeft = first.css('margin-Left');
    first.css({
        marginLeft: 0 - fow,
        position:  'relative',
        left:       0 - ulPaddingLeft
    });
    last.css('position', 'relative');
    el.animate({ width: w + widthDiff }, 1500);
    first.animate({ left: 0 }, 250, function() {
        first.animate({ marginLeft: oldMarginLeft }, 1000, function() {
            last.animate({ left: ulPaddingRight }, 250, function() {
                last.remove();

                el.css({
                    width:   'auto',
                    overflow: 'visible'
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```